# Facebook log out not working

Tags: facebook-graph-api, logout

Our app uses Facebook app API and as of this morning, our log out just stopped working.  When you click logout on our app, it will log you out of Facebook, but our app still detects a Facebook session and allows the user to stay logged in.

We also noticed that the fbsr_* cookie isn't being deleted.  Although I'm not sure if it's suppose to be.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am having the same issue. I went ahead in php and did $facebook->destroySession(); which helped however as of this morning it is still returning the same things. I am thinking its a bug on the facebook side.

I made a post here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/245362365535898